# Fcm Notification not receive Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am working with FCM for notification, and I have done all things and process guide by Google, but still notification not receive on device after sending message by FCM using bundle id.

I also get FCM token in Log but device token not showing and not null showing, How can I see my message send by FCM, show in my log?

My Appdeleget.m file is

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "HomeCategaryScreen.h"
#import "CollectionMenuViewController.h"
#import "Stripe.h"
#import "Header.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "PaymentSucessFullVC.h"
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#import "Firebase.h"



#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
// running iOS 10 and above.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
@end
#endif

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif
#define IS_IPHONE6P   ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736)
#define IS_IPHONE6  ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667)
#define ALERT_VIEW_TAG 3456
static BOOL internetWorking;

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:StripePublishLiveKey];

    self.subCategoryID = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    self.cust_ID       = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    self.itemCountOnCart = 0;
    self.cust_ID = @1;
    NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults valueForKey:@"logIn"] ) {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        CollectionMenuViewController
        *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CollectionMenuViewController"];

        // self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [self isNetworkReachable];


        // [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setDebugMode:YES];
        [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
        //[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

        // [Crashlytics.sharedInstance  crash];

        //or the homeController
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    }

    //making a view to root view
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:164.0/255.0 green:44.0/255.0 blue:3.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];







    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }
    return YES;
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

+(AppDelegate*) getDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

-(BOOL)isNetworkReachable
{
    Reachability *internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

    [internetReachable startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            internetWorking = NO;
            [self addNetworkAlertView];
            return NO;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            internetWorking = YES;
            [self removeNetworkAlert];
            return YES;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            // ReachableViaMobileNetwork:
            internetWorking = YES;
            [self removeNetworkAlert];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}


- (void )addNetworkAlertView
{
    if(internetWorking)
    {
        [self removeNetworkAlert];
        return;
    }

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView *view = [window viewWithTag:ALERT_VIEW_TAG];
    if(view)
    {
        [window bringSubviewToFront:view];
        return;
    }

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"offline_bar"];
    CGSize imgSize = image.size;

    UIImageView* bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, imgSize.width, imgSize.height)];
    bgImageView.image = image;

    CGFloat xOffset = (window.frame.size.width-imgSize.width)/2;

    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset,window.bounds.size.height,imgSize.width, imgSize.height)];
    //    [view setBackgroundColor:kColor(40, 40, 40, 0.8)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
    [view setTag:ALERT_VIEW_TAG];

    [view addSubview:bgImageView];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height-5)];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [label setText:@"You are currently offline!"];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:IS_IPHONE6P?14.0f:IS_IPHONE6?13.0f:12]];


    //    UIButton* crossButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width-60, 0, 60, view.frame.size.height)];
    //    [crossButton addTarget:self action:@selector(offlineBannerViewCrossButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //    [crossButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offline_bar_cross"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //    [view addSubview:crossButton];

    [window addSubview:view];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:view];

    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    //    frame.size.height = 0;
    frame.origin.y = window.bounds.size.height;
    view.frame = frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        //        frame.size.height = 30;
        frame.origin.y = window.bounds.size.height-view.frame.size.height-50;
        view.frame = frame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}



- (void)moveNetworkAlertYPosition:(float)value
{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView *alertView = [window viewWithTag:ALERT_VIEW_TAG];
    if(alertView)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            CGRect frame = alertView.frame;
            frame.origin.y += value;
            alertView.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

    }
}

-(void)removeNetworkAlert
{
    @try {

        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        UIView *alertView = [window viewWithTag:ALERT_VIEW_TAG];
        alertView.tag = 0;
        if(alertView)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

                CGRect frame = alertView.frame;
                //            frame.size.height = 0.0f;
                frame.origin.y = window.frame.size.height;
                alertView.frame = frame;

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                alertView.tag = 0;
                [alertView removeFromSuperview];
            }];

        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
    @finally {

    }
}



// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[Messaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[Messaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[Messaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set [Messaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel to YES.
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"Received data message: %@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
// [END ios_10_data_message]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs device token can be paired to
// the FCM registration token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs device token here.
    // [Messaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
}
@end
```

and my log is

```
> 

2017-07-13 09:50:53.608 Chahat Restaurant[790:25333] Simulator user
    > has requested new graphics quality: 100 2017-07-13 09:50:53.783 Chahat
    > Restaurant[790] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The
    > AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not
    > function properly. Learn more at 
 2017-07-13
    > 09:50:53.786 Chahat Restaurant[790] <Notice>
    > [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40002000
    > started 2017-07-13 09:50:53.786 Chahat Restaurant[790] <Notice>
    > [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the
    > following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
    > ) 2017-07-13 09:50:53.957 Chahat Restaurant[790]
    > <Notice> [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote
    > Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver
    > handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and
    > set it to NO 2017-07-13 09:50:55.152637 Chahat Restaurant[790:25333]
    > [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    >   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
    > you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
    > figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
    > unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483660 RBTextField:0x7fa464c1ba10.width == 300   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000484f10 H:[RBTextField:0x7fa464c1ba10]-(0)-|   (active, names:
    > '|':UIView:0x7fa464f02010 )>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000484010 H:|-(0)-[RBTextField:0x7fa464c1ba10]   (active, names:
    > '|':UIView:0x7fa464f02010 )>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048c710 UIView:0x7fa464f02010.width == 0.937*UIView:0x7fa464f02780.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000486900 UIView:0x7fa464f02780.width == UIView:0x7fa464d0be20.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029dbf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fa464d0be20.width == 414 
    > (active)>" )
    > 
    > Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    > <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483660 RBTextField:0x7fa464c1ba10.width ==
    > 300   (active)>
    > 
    > Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
    > to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
    > UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
    > <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2017-07-13 09:50:55.154207
    > Chahat Restaurant[790:25333] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to
    > simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the
    > constraints in the following list is one you don't want.      Try this: 
    >       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
    > expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
    > constraints and fix it.  (
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029fcc0 RBTextField:0x7fa464e089d0.width == 300   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080004897e0 H:[RBTextField:0x7fa464e089d0]-(0)-|   (active, names:
    > '|':UIView:0x7fa464f02920 )>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000483e30 H:|-(0)-[RBTextField:0x7fa464e089d0]   (active, names:
    > '|':UIView:0x7fa464f02920 )>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000487ee0 UIView:0x7fa464f02920.width == UIView:0x7fa464f02010.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048c710 UIView:0x7fa464f02010.width == 0.937*UIView:0x7fa464f02780.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000486900 UIView:0x7fa464f02780.width == UIView:0x7fa464d0be20.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029dbf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fa464d0be20.width == 414 
    > (active)>" )
    > 
    > Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    > <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029fcc0 RBTextField:0x7fa464e089d0.width ==
    > 300   (active)>
    > 
    > Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
    > to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
    > UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
    > <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2017-07-13 09:50:55.156005
    > Chahat Restaurant[790:25333] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to
    > simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the
    > constraints in the following list is one you don't want.      Try this: 
    >       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
    > expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
    > constraints and fix it.  (
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048d980 RBTextField:0x7fa464c19cb0.width == 300   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048d4d0 H:|-(0)-[RBTextField:0x7fa464c19cb0]   (active, names:
    > '|':UIView:0x7fa464f02350 )>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000094820 H:[RBTextField:0x7fa464c19cb0]-(0)-|   (active, names:
    > '|':UIView:0x7fa464f02350 )>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048c710 UIView:0x7fa464f02010.width == 0.937*UIView:0x7fa464f02780.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048bf90 UIView:0x7fa464f02350.width == UIView:0x7fa464f02010.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000486900 UIView:0x7fa464f02780.width == UIView:0x7fa464d0be20.width   (active)>",
    >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029dbf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fa464d0be20.width == 414 
    > (active)>" )
    > 
    > Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    > <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800048d980 RBTextField:0x7fa464c19cb0.width ==
    > 300   (active)>
    > 
    > Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
    > to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
    > UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
    > <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. 2017-07-13 09:50:55.433 Chahat
    > Restaurant[790:25333] Unable to register for remote notifications:
    > Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are
    > not supported in the simulator"
    > UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not
    > supported in the simulator} 2017-07-13 09:50:55.445 Chahat
    > Restaurant[790] <Error> [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in
    > application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote
    > notifications are not supported in the simulator 2017-07-13
    > 09:50:55.445 Chahat Restaurant[790] <Notice>
    > [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase
    > Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set
    > the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
    > 2017-07-13 09:50:56.850 Chahat Restaurant[790] <Warning>
    > [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search
    > Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled. 2017-07-13 09:50:56.853 Chahat
    > Restaurant[790] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase
    > Analytics enabled 2017-07-13 09:50:57.646 Chahat Restaurant[790:25333]
    > FCM registration token:
    > e86KpLRV4M8:APA91bGAzMt2gsD5IPdy837nc_cxtSQBcU0m4uPFcqkZUmSBDdB0gf9-nd82FYY14qXetqlrG59RStFZkiUP-8sNPiRnpXsbzcFXwodSru1E8zS2GkM7JSCkmzv4Mx5SYxiz0RMispdm
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Once u add all the framework, in your log also showing most framework errors only.

Then in your info.plist file

**FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled=NO**

Comment: not understand, u told me that i go to plist file and proxyenabled=No. right?

Comment: ya u add pl;ist file that.

Check u add all frameworks added.

Comment: Just u copy paste this in info plist: 

    FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled 

Then Set Boolean No.

Comment: Adding Frameworks : 

In General --> Link Frameworks --> + button

Add Following Frameworks : 
AdSupport
CoreLocation
AvFoundation
Avkit
iAd
UiKit
Foundation

Comment: Added these framework are done, then what should i do, in info.plist

Comment: In info plist u click +option come there u add these line: 

Add these line copy paste: 

FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled

Comment: Ya there is no error but still Device token not Showing <null>

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

NSLog(@"Registered for notification device token: %@", devToken);

[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:devToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown];

[self connectToFcm];

const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];

}


Check above line there or not

Comment: i hav this - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs device token here.
    // [Messaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
}

Comment: but its not called because log does not show "APNs device token retrieved:" Note: i have not using real device i am work with simulator. but why method are not called atleast they show null if device not connected